# How to render banners alongside featured items in home page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I'm making a custom template form joomla 2.5, and one of the goals for the development is to include a banner after each featured article iteration.

After a long research I can render a banner into **/template_name/html/com_content/featured/default_item.php** with the following code:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
$position = "nota";
$options = array('style' => 'raw');
echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null);
```

But the issue is that each iteration resets the banner list so I have the same banner repeated with each featured article.

I tried to include the banner module using the same code in **/template_name/html/com_content/featured/default.php** without success. Lately I'd try with `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="nota" style="raw" />` and it didn't works too, so I will appreciate any help to solve this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in two ways.

### The right way

Copy and rename the banner module (fx. to `mybanners`), change the `getList()` method in the helper file to retrieve different banners on each call. This could fx. be:

```
class modMybannersHelper
{
    static function &getList(&$params)
    {
        static $index = 0;

        JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_banners/models', 'BannersModel');
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $app      = JFactory::getApplication();
        $keywords = explode(',', $document->getMetaData('keywords'));

        $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Banners', 'BannersModel', array('ignore_request'=>true));
        $model->setState('filter.client_id', (int) $params->get('cid'));
        $model->setState('filter.category_id', $params->get('catid', array()));
        $model->setState('list.limit', 1);
        $model->setState('list.start', $index++);
        $model->setState('filter.ordering', $params->get('ordering'));
        $model->setState('filter.tag_search', $params->get('tag_search'));
        $model->setState('filter.keywords', $keywords);
        $model->setState('filter.language', $app->getLanguageFilter());

        $banners = $model->getItems();
        $model->impress();

        return $banners;
    }
}
```

This is just a sketch; you still need to handle the case of `$index` being greater than the number of records.

### The hacky way

The retrieval code has only one port open to inject conditions - the documents's keywords.
So you could (in your template file) store the original keywords an replace them with a keyword to identify a banner. The banner must have the same keyword in that case.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$keywords = $document->getMetaData('keywords');
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
$position = "nota";
$options  = array('style' => 'raw');
$document->setMetaData('keywords', 'banner_key');
echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null);
$document->setMetaData('keywords', $keywords);
```

Either way, *caching* may prevent that from work, so you might have to turn it off (I didn't check that).